# Hide part of String.Format within a ComboBox.Item

Tags: mysql, string, vb.net, combobox

Is it possible to hide part of `String.Format`?

This my code:

```
'Select Product'
Try
    MysqlConn.Close()
    MysqlConn.Open()
    Dim Query As String
    Query = "select id, name,id_maker, id_types from product ORDER BY name ASC"
    COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
    READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
    While READER.Read
        Dim sName = READER.GetString("name")
        Dim sMaker = READER.GetString("id_maker")
        Dim sTypes = READER.GetString("id_types")
        Dim sId = READER.GetString("id")

        'ComboBox1.Items.Add(sName)'
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(String.Format("{0}|{1}|{2}|{3}", sName, sMaker, sTypes, sId))


    End While
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
Finally
    MysqlConn.Dispose()
End Try
'Select Product'
```

I want to hide {3} which is `sId` in the `ComboBox`, because later I need to use a query where the `ComboBox1.Text` is used and the id is necessary.

Comment: If you dont want the user to see the Id, dont add it to the string format.  If you need it in code. use a datasource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could change the way you are assigning the data to the `ComboBox`.

First thing to do is change the query and use [CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat):

```
SELECT id, CONCAT(name,'|',id_maker,'|',id_types) AS value FROM product ORDER BY name ASC
```

I would also implement [Using](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx):

> Managed resources are disposed of by the .NET Framework garbage collector (GC) without any extra coding on your part. You do not need a Using block for managed resources. However, you can still use a Using block to force the disposal of a managed resource instead of waiting for the garbage collector.

You also don't need the `READER`. Instead load the data into a `DataTable` and assign that to the `.DataSource` property on the `ComboBox`.

Your code would look something like this:

```
Using con As New MySqlConnection(connectionString)
      cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT id, CONCAT(name,'|',id_maker,'|',id_types) AS value FROM product ORDER BY name ASC", con)

    con.Open()

    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader())

    ComboBox1.DataSource = dt
    ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "value"
    ComboBox1.ValueMember = "id"
End Using
```

You can now get the `id` with this bit of code:

```
ComboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString()
```

And you can get the text with this bit of code:

```
ComboBox1.Text
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i use now that and works

```
Dim connetionString As String = Nothing
    Dim connection As MySqlConnection
    Dim command As MySqlCommand
    Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter()
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim sql As String = Nothing
    'connetionString = "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=databasename;User ID=userid;Password=yourpassword"
    'sql = "select id,name from product"
    sql = "SELECT id, CONCAT(name,' | ',id_maker,' | ',id_types) AS value FROM product ORDER BY name ASC"
    'connection = New MySqlConnection(connetionString)
    connection = New MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("xCollectibles.My.MySettings.xcollectiblesConnectionString").ToString)
    Try
        connection.Open()
        command = New MySqlCommand(sql, connection)
        adapter.SelectCommand = command
        adapter.Fill(ds)
        adapter.Dispose()
        command.Dispose()
        connection.Close()
        ComboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        ComboBox1.ValueMember = "id"
        ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "value"



    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! ")
    End Try
```

Thanks you..